# How to call the child class method in parent class in php

Tags: php, oop

```
<?php

class mainClass
{
    public function demo()
    {
        return "You have entertered to demo1";
    }

}

class childClass extends mainClass
{
    public function demo2()
    {
        return $this->demo();
    }
    public function demo3()
    {
        return "You have entered to demo3";
    }
}
```

I want to call `demo3` method of `childClass` in `mainClass`. As i am new to oops i am a bit confused. I am also thinking about abstract class for this. But i have not enough idea about abstract classes.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Just put demo3 in the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? You don't have to call mainClass, because you extend it by the new childClass. I also added the echo in demo3 to show the result on the screen.

```
<?php

class mainClass
{
    public function demo()
    {
        return "You have entertered to demo1";
    }

}

class childClass extends mainClass
{
    public function demo2()
    {
        return $this->demo();
    }
    public function demo3()
    {
        echo "You have entered to demo3";
    }
}
$test = new childClass;
$test->demo3();

?>
```